# ngfor with li : how to trigger update call and send the value to component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How do I send 'countryCode.Display' value with updateCountryCode() call.

```
<div class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-block dropdown-toggle dropdownlistwifi form-control" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ SelectedCountryCode }}</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownList">
            <li *ngFor="let countryCode of AllEuCountryCodeValues"><a (click)="updateCountryCode('countryCode.Display')">{{countryCode.Display}}</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `updateCountryCode('countryCode.Display')` passes the string `countryCode.Display` to the function. Does it do what you want if you remove the quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass the reference to the object in, not a string.

```
<li *ngFor="let countryCode of AllEuCountryCodeValues">
  <a (click)="updateCountryCode(countryCode.Display)">{{countryCode.Display}}</a>
</li>
```

`updateCountryCode(countryCode.Display)` vs `updateCountryCode('countryCode.Display')`, the second option passes a string, the first one whatever the value of the object is.